# How change non nullable column to nullable column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Am getting the values from the table using select statement.

```
select * from samp
```

Result:

```
     id           name      date
     1              a       20/1/2013
     2              b       31/1/2013
```

Its shows all columns and values.In that i have date field with values. i want make this column with the value to null.I.e while using select statement i want to make  date field to null.

```
select id,name,date from samp
```

Result:

```
       id          name       date
        1           a          null
        2           b          null
```

please give your suggestion.

Comment: You want to change the nullability of a column in a table through a select statement?  Do you just not want the values from the column?  If that's the case, simply specify the columns in the select statement that you do want (rather than using `*`).

Comment: In other words, if you have 4 columns and only want the first three, use `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM samp`, where col1, col2, col3 would be the names of the columns you want.

Comment: yes i dont want values for that column.while i using "select date from samp" it has to show null vaule for this column.how to make null while using select statement

Comment: Please be more concise with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want "fake" the value of a column in a result set, try

```
select id, name, NULL as [date] from samp
```

If you want to change the underlying data, do

```
UPDATE samp set [date] = NULL
```

Comment: my doubt is to set null value to the all records in the date field.how to set null value to date filed

Comment: any other method with out update value to null.i dont want to change the value in db.but when i using select statement it has to show null value.what condition i have to use in select

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the values of a particular column from a table, simply specify the columns that you do want.

For example, say you have a table with 4 columns (Number, Date, Address, Email).  If you didn't want the Date column in your result set, simply omit it from the list of columns in the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT Number, Address, Email FROM MyTable
```

Alternatively, if you *must* have a NULL value, you should be able to do this:

```
SELECT Number, NULL, Address, Email FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
SELECT Number, Address, Email,Null as MyDateField FROM MyTable
```